# xsd.exe options - how to ignore constraint error message?

Tags: xml, xsd.exe

I have the following error message:

```
C:\Users\humphrt\Desktop\AVV>xsd AVV038526.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3038]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Error: There was an error processing 'AVV038526.xml'.
  - Cannot add constraint to DataTable 'REEL' which is a child table in two nest
ed relations.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".
```

I validated my xml at W3.org, [here](http://validator.w3.org/check)

> This document was successfully checked as well-formed XML!

Is there an issue with xsd.exe that I am unaware of? According to W3.org I have well-formed xml. Because of this I am surprised that xsd.exe is giving me an error message.

I read a number of online threads about this issue. In one of these threads a Microsoft worker suggested using option explicit of xsd.exe. I do not see "explicit" listed in the documentation of xsd.exe as an option.

I could use help figuring this out so that I may generate *.xsd from my *.xml file.